# google+ like button isn't working in django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, google-plus

I used this code for my web page

```
<div class="g-plusone" size="small"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
   })();
  </script>
```

but when I click on g+ button, nothing is happening, i mean no pop-up windows like when we do for facebook/twitter? am i missing something in this code?

Answer (score 0):

No it is working perfectly,

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/rgTcj/)

```
(function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
   })();
```

Debug the error using chrome developer tool. It is useful.